# O365 MS Teams MessageCard img alignment issue in markdown text

Tags: css, markdown, microsoft-teams, webhooks, office365connectors

I'm using a legacy MessageCard type to send to a Microsoft Teams channel connector. This card is used to accept user-supplied markdown as the text:

```json
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "title": "title",
    "summary": "summary",
    "markdown": true,
    "text": user_markdown,
}
```

A common source for the markdown is to be provided something like a changelog, using list items, images, and text:

```
# Release Notes

What's new:

* <img style="width:16px; height:16px; vertical-align:middle;" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,..." /> Issue 1
* <img style="width:16px; height:16px; vertical-align:middle;" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,..." /> Issue 2
```

This works great and the markdown is rendered perfectly on desktop and web Teams clients.

[image: good layout in desktop and web]

But I have found that on the Teams mobile app there is some kind of different layout being applied to the markdown when displaying the same card that looks fine in other clients.

[image: bad layout in mobile]

Per this example you can see that it ignores the fixed image size and seems to enlarge it to the equivalent of "1.5em", and aligns it before the list item. I've been trying to fix this with various style settings to the img tag (float, display, ...), or wrapping the content in each list item to control the layout as a whole. But it seems the mobile client is applying some extra style to the img to make it display as "block" or similar.

Is it possible to correct the way images are aligned in this case?

Update:

Here is a complete repro for testing purposes:

**teams_card.json**

```json
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "title": "title",
    "summary": "summary",
    "markdown": true,
    "text": "# Release Notes\n\nWhat's new:\n\n* <img style=\"width:16px; height:16px; vertical-align:middle;\" src=\"data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTYiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgdmlld2JveD0iMCAwIDE2IDE2Ij48ZyBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBmaWxsLXJ1bGU9ImV2ZW5vZGQiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDEuNzc3QzAgLjc5Ni43OTYgMCAxLjc3NyAwaDEyLjQ0NkMxNS4yMDQgMCAxNiAuNzk2IDE2IDEuNzc3djEyLjQ0NmMwIC45ODEtLjc5NiAxLjc3Ny0xLjc3NyAxLjc3N0gxLjc3N0ExLjc3OCAxLjc3OCAwIDAgMSAwIDE0LjIyM1YxLjc3N3oiIGZpbGw9IiNGRjU2MzAiLz48Y2lyY2xlIGZpbGw9IiNGRkYiIGN4PSI4IiBjeT0iOCIgcj0iNCIvPjwvZz48L3N2Zz4=\" /> Issue 1\n"
}
```

**Sending to an existing MS Teams channel connector:**

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "@teams_card.json" https://<company>.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/<id path>
```

Comment: Could you please share any repro steps, how you are sending message card having markdown text?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, sure. I have updated the question with a complete repro.

Comment: We are able to repro this issue. We have raised a bug for the same and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any further update regarding any alternative or if it's by design behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT that's amazing! Is there a public link to the issue that I could track for internal issues at my studio?

Comment: Sorry, we can't share the bug link. We are following up with engineering team and will inform you once we have any update. Thanks!